# How to transfer data between main function and threads?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to store the threads that I have created in my main function in an array and later access them in my Thread class. What would be the best way to do this?. Below is the structure of my code.

Main.cpp:

```
int main(){
//do something

while ((new_socket = socket.Accept())) {
        std::thread mythread(&Myclass::MyThread, &myclass, 
                std::move(new_socket), para1);
        // I want to store the above threads created in an array which can later be accessed in a different thread class
    }
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyThread(....){
I want to access the array of threads here.
}
```

I have tried mutex and cv and add these threads into a queue but it is generating many errors. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you know how to store objects in arrays? Now just do the same thing with the thread objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if array fits the bill - do you know how many threads there will be?

Maybe a vector is better:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads; // could be a member - used to store the threads

while ((new_socket = socket.Accept()))
{
    // Construct the thread in place inside the vector
    threads.emplace_back(&Myclass::MyThread, &myclass, std::move(new_socket), para1);
}
```

Now you have all your threads neatly in a vector (note I did not test this with you code because there is not enough of it to test... its not a complete example)